# Why the UTC time is different in different time zones?

Tags: python

I am using python module to get the utctime

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

but in IST timezone, it is giving the value as

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 20, 17, 24, 37, 674000)
```

and in EST timezone, getting

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 20, 14, 24, 54, 865419)
```

I think value needs to be same just like GMT time, but why is the difference?

I found that in linux system,when I run date command, PST time is shown but with EST

```
Tue Jan 20 09:35:55 EST 2015
```

09:35 is the current PST time, but why it is giving EST?

Comment: Are you changing timezone without changing the time?

Comment: I am connecting to a linux system using putty which is there in US, that linux system is showing EST time if I run date command and I am working from time India time zone (GMT+5:30)

Comment: The machines are likely misconfigured (wrong timezone and utc clock set incorrectly to compensate). How thats fixed in linux depends on whether you are using ntp and is a good fit for serverfault.

Comment: To add: As I understand it, Linux computers have an "absolute time since 1969" and calculate current time by using that plus the timezone, so it is saying EST because it thinks it IS EST. Computer clocks are often (usually?) not automatically calibrated.

Answer (score 1):

The computer in the EST time zone has the wrong system time.

That's it.

If it's showing "EST" but giving PST-consistent time, the system clock is wrong.

Comment: Whoops. I shouldn't even be here.

Comment: Its okay to get it wrong... but maybe a good idea to delete the answer and reduce the cruft.

Comment: Edited the answer instead.